# How to italicize part of caption in kable

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have created a table using the `kableExtra` package. Is there a way in which I can italicize the second sentence in the caption

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

head(iris) %>% kable() %>% kable_styling() %>% 
  footnote(general= 'Here is my footnote. I want this sentence in italics')
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `<i>/</i>`

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
head(iris) %>%
   kable() %>% 
   kable_styling() %>% 
   footnote(general="Here is my footnote. <i>I want this sentence in italics</i>", escape = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]